# SQL- Calculating Next Bi-Weekly Date between Start Date and End Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the next weekly and bi-weekly date based on a start date and end date. The data currently looks like:

| RecordID | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXXX | 12/8/2021 | 07/28/2022 |

Based off of the current date (5/31/2022) the next bi-weekly date would be on 6/8/2022.

I have figured out how to calculate the next weekly date based off of the current date but have been unable to figure out how to take into account the time period start date for calculating the next bi-weekly date from the current date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Sorry for being unclear in my original post.

Background:

- I have data on scheduled appointments for individuals and I need to
  find the next available appointment.
- Appointments can be either weekly or bi-weekly (14 days), each type of appointment as a reason code showing if it is bi-weekly or weekly.
- Appointments occur from Monday to Friday.
- Each record has a Start Date and End Date for a scheduled appointment, however this can occur over many months (i.e. every Monday from 1/1/2021 to 1/1/2023).

Data Structure:

| RecordID | Opening Type | Appointment Time | Start Date | Appointment Day | Appointment End Date | Reason Code | Current Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXXX | Bi-Weekly | 10:00 AM | 12/08/2021 | Wednesday | 07/28/2022 | 2 | 05/31/2022 |

What I have done:

DATEADD METHOD:

```
case when cast(EndDateTime as date) = cast(current_timestamp as date) then cast(EndDateTime as date)
when Reason_PK = 4519 and cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) > cast(StartDateTime as date) then DATEADD(WK,1,cast(StartDateTime as date))
when Reason_PK = 4518 and cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) > cast(StartDateTime as date) then DATEADD(WK,2, cast(StartDateTime as date))
else cast(StartDateTime as date) end as next_appointment_date_add
```

WHY IT HASN'T WORKED:

For future openings or openings that end on the current date this method works perfectly, however when looking at appointments that occur over many months (i.e. start date 12/8/2021 and end date 7/28/2022) it does not take into account that I need to pull the next available Wednesday's date (i.e. 6/1/2022 for weekly or 6/8 for bi-weekly). However, it can be difficult to know where the bi-weekly date falls on. For example if the start date was 12/1/2021 the next opening for a weekly opening would be 6/1/2022 **but** it would also be on 6/1/2022 for a bi-weekly opening.

OTHER METHOD:

I have tried pulling the next available date based off of the day name utilizing the code below (it is messy and unruly which may be why it has been difficult to implement):

```
case when cast(EndDateTime as date) = cast(current_timestamp as date) then cast(EndDateTime as date) 
when reason_pk = 4519 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Monday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date)  then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 2, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 2 then 0 else 7 end )) 
when reason_pk = 4519 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Tuesday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 3, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
      + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 3 then 0 else 7 end ))
 when reason_pk = 4519 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Wednesday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 4, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 4 then 0 else 7 end ))
 when reason_pk = 4519 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Thursday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 5, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 5 then 0 else 7 end ))
when reason_pk = 4519 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Friday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 6, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 6 then 0 else 7 end )) 
when reason_pk = 4518 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Monday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date)  then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 2, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 2 then 0 else 14 end )) 
when reason_pk = 4518 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Tuesday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 3, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
      + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 3 then 0 else 14 end ))
 when reason_pk = 4518 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Wednesday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 4, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 4 then 0 else 14 end ))
 when reason_pk = 4518 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Thursday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 5, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 5 then 0 else 14 end ))
when reason_pk = 4518 and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, StartDateTime) = 'Friday' and case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(StartDateTime as date) else cast(StartDateTime as date) END <> cast(EndDateTime as date) then convert(DATE, dateadd(day, 6, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END  - datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime < cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END)
       + case when datepart(dw, case when StartDateTime <= cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) then cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as date) else StartDateTime END) < 6 then 0 else 14 end ))
  else cast(StartDateTime as date)
  end as Next_Opening
```

Expected Output:

|RecordID | Opening Type | Appointment Time   | Start Date | Appointment Day | Appointment End Date | Reason Code | Current Date | Next Opening |

| XXXXXX       | Bi-Weekly | 10:00 AM| 12/08/2021 | Wednesday | 07/28/2022 | 2 |05/31/2022 | 06/08/2022 |

| YYYYYY | Bi-Weekly | 10:00 AM| 12/01/2021 | Wednesday | 07/28/2022 | 2 |05/31/2022 | 06/01/2022 |

Sorry for the lack of clarity in my original post, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, post your current attempt and the expected results.

Comment: for those of us that do not have english as mothertongue, what does `bi-weekly` means ?

Comment: We can't read your mind nor know your business rules. How exactly do you determine that June 8 is the "next" date based on a current date of May 31? When you say "bi-weekly" do you really mean semi-monthly (and even that is a stretch of imagination)?

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the lack of clarity. I have expanded upon my original post. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD`

- `DATEADD(wk,1,StartDate)` for weekly
- `DATEADD(wk,2,StartDate)` for bi-weekly in the sense of every 2 weeks

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '07/26/2023'
DECLARE @NumWeeks INT

SELECT DATEADD(wk, 2, @StartDate)

SET @NumWeeks = DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, GetDate())

SELECT DATEADD(wk, @NumWeeks + 1, @StartDate)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '07/26/2023'
DECLARE @NumWeeks INT
DECLARE @WeekInMonth INT 

SET @WeekInMonth = (day(datediff(d,0, GETDATE())/7*7)-1)/7+1
SET @NumWeeks = DATEDIFF(wk, @StartDate, GetDate())

IF ((@WeekInMonth = 2) OR (@WeekInMonth = 4))
     SET @NumWeeks = @NumWeeks + 1

SELECT DATEADD(wk, @NumWeeks, @StartDate)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: You are aware that you can [edit] your posts for improvement, instead of adding more copies, aren't you? You also can delete them, once you did add more copies. If you don't delete you'd probably do well in adding an explanation of what the additional insight is, which each of the two posts on its own contributes so that it makes both of the two answer valuable and worth to keep. You want to avoid the impression that you only create multiple posts for lack of understanding the editing and other options you have. Seeing that you never took the [tour], that otherwise seems too plausible.

Comment: @Yunnosch - Thanks for your tips on posting, I will be sure to work towards improving that.  Just to be clear - The edit ability was not working at the time and I did not want to leave the code as was.   Obviously, you would not want two answers together as such.  I also want to point out that your tone in your responses is very condescending and not a great way to communicate to other people.  We are all hear to contribute and learn, don't lecture people, just be straight to the point as in your first response.

Comment: There are two responses because the first one is the standard canned response for all those many many users who post code-only answers. You got that for each of your code-only post. The second post I felt would better address that fact that you have posted two separate posts, code-only or not. If you elaborate on how the editing of your own posts seemed to be impossible I will try to debug that situation. Independently of that, you still have those two posts up and the slightly more recent one declares itself to be an update - i.e. not a separate post with its own contributed insight.

Comment: Feel free to flag any of my comment as rude if you really see them that way. But allow me to point out, as constructively as I can make it, that you still have two code-only answers, the separate merits of which are in themselves unclear (among other things because of lack of explanation) and as a pair almost explicitly state that one of them is obsolete. Not deleting them does not match the impression that you want to contribute valuable insight and instead gives the impression that without a good reason you neither use the (now working if I got you right) edit or delete options.

Comment: This is what I can't stand about this forum, please put this much effort into other more important things in life.